# Posts missing in Dashboard, but are still on blog pages

Tags: posts

After a recent update I received a message from a customer saying they couldn't leave a post to one of my blogs.  I went to the Dashboard, and the menu item "Posts" and "See all posts" now come up with zero posts, although it looks like all the original posts are still on the blog pages they were written to.  Also, the "View Posts" link at the very top menu strip is mapped to the URL of my welcome page now and will only lead to it.

hhoyt

I tried disabling all plugins, all posts are still not reflected in the 'Posts' page in WP Dashboard, although they are all still on their respective Blog pages.  Any other ideas?

Thanks for the help!
hhoyt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of a plugin or theme incompatibility. Please turn off all plugins and change themes. If that works, start enabling each plugin one by one to find the source.

You can also install the [Health Check plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/). You can use its troubleshooting to have all plugins disabled and the theme changed for you. This will occur while you are still logged in and should not effect normal site visitors.